# component cross communication using button

Tags: angular, typescript

Original Behavior: on clicking the button, it toggles the div (close to open, open to close)
ChildComponent.html

```
<div *ngIf="showFiller" class="sidenav">
<p>Hey</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <button (click)="showFiller = !showFiller" mat-raised-button>
    Toggle extra text
  </button>
  <p> Hello </p>
</div>
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
showFiller = false;
```

Request: Now i need to move the button to parent component, but need the same behavior in child. So button should be in parent, action should be represented in child
This is the code i tried

ParentComponent.html

```
<mat-icon mat-button (click)="toggle()" class="index">menu</mat-icon>
```

ParentComponent.ts

```
show: boolean = true;
  toggle(){
    this.show = !this.show;
    this.show;
    console.log(this.show);
  }
```

ChildComponent.html

```
<div *ngIf="showFiller" class="sidenav">
<p>Hey</p>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <!-- <button (click)="showFiller = !showFiller" mat-raised-button>
    Toggle extra text
  </button> -->
  <p> Hello </p>
</div>
```

ChildComponent.ts

```
@Input() show: boolean;
  showFiller: boolean = true;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.showFiller = this.show;
    console.log(this.showFiller);
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: boolean) {
    this.showFiller = this.show;
    console.log(this.showFiller);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are keeping a another state in your child component which is not necessary. Your parent component determines the state and passes that to your child component. The task of the child component is only to show/hide the div based on the input.

Example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4pff9m

Comment: hi thanks for the support, I made the suggested changes here [https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kynvnc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.html], but the button click in one component is not reflected in second component

Comment: Well you have to pass the show variable to your child component and you are duplicatiing state again in your child component (show and showFiller variable). only 1 boolean is necessary